# Can database references in mongodb reference two databases?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using MongoDB via mongooose. Can [database references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)  reference two databases at the same time?

```
field_name: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'collectionA',// can I reference collectionA and collectionB too?
    required: true,
},
```

See code above.

The field, `field_name`, can be an objectId from collectionA or collectionB. How can I reflect that in my mongoose schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for mongoose [dynamic reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref) via refPath.

```
const someSchema = new Schema({
  field_name: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    refPath: 'onCollection'
  },
  onCollection: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['collectionA', 'collectionB']
  }
});
```

In this case, Instead of a hardcoded model name in `ref`, `refPath` means Mongoose
will look at the `onCollection` property to find the right model.
For example if we have this document:

```
 {
   field_name: some_id,
   onCollection: 'collectionA'
 }
```

`Collection.find().populate('field_name')` will populate the field from `collectionA`. And if the `onCollection` field was valued with `collectionB`, it would have populated it from `collectionB`.

This scenario only works if you want to reference one collection at a time, but the collection is dynamic.

---

If you need to reference both collections at the same time, there is no mongoose schema design to support array of references as far as I know.

You can just ignore `ref` in your schema, and pass in the value of ref when you want to populate:

```
populate({
  path: 'field_name',
  model: 'collectionA'   
})
```

Then you can have multiple populates. Same applies for [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Comment: Yes, what I was looking for is mongoose dynamic reference via refPath. Is there a need for refPath if all of your queries will be aggregations? Does refpath validate that the provided mongodb objectId belongs to the referenced collection?